# MATLAB: Function to display name of class instance (object)

Tags: oop, matlab

I am stuck with what I expect should be something relatively simple to do. I am writing a class `Superclass` such that:

```
 Superclass < handle
```

and then:

```
MyClass < Superclass
```

`MyClass` contains function `DisplayObjectName`, which should do what the name suggests. That is, display the name of the class instance (object).

For example, I create an object:

```
TestObject = MyClass(inputvariable);
```

Then I would like to have a function such that when I call

```
TestObject.DisplayObjectName()
```

the output would be

```
ans = TestObject
```

I could not seem to find a way to do that. Any ideas? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The `inputname` function seems to do the trick.

```
classdef SuperClass < handle
    methods
        function displayObjectName(self)
            disp(inputname(1))
        end
    end
end
```

Then

```
classdef MyClass < SuperClass
end
```

And

```
>> TestObject = MyClass;
>> TestObject.displayObjectName
TestObject
```

Comment: `inputname` is how most MATLAB-implemented versions of `display` get their job done.

Comment: This won't work if you call `displayObjectName` from within the class definition, for what it's worth; also see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793694/matlab-class-with-knowledge-of-instance-name-in-the-constructor .