# Matlab class with knowledge of instance name in the constructor

Tags: matlab, constructor, instance, uniqueidentifier

I would like to have a class which, in its constructor, can have knowledge  (extract as a string) its instance name.

For the moment I worked the name extraction out like this:

```
classdef mysession

methods (Access = public)

  function this=mysession (varargin)
    this.cargs=varargin;
    this.built=false;
  end

  function id=build(this)
    id=this.mynameis;
    this.id = id;
    %% instructions needing id 
    built=true;
  end

  function name = mynameis (this)
    name=evalin ('caller', 'inputname');
  end
end

properties  (Access=private)
    id
    built
    cargs
end
end
```

which requires the ugly

```
A = mysession;  A.build
```

syntax in order to work...

Comment: Why do you need to do this. Since a `handle` class is passed by reference, you can technically have *two* variables that point to the *same* object, therefore it has *two* names

Comment: sorry, I just copied some code which was given to me and this is my first Matlab class. deriving from handle would not be correct - the instances should also be noncopyable as they actually refer to an external database  of objects (thus the need for a unique identifier).

Comment: WE can likely give you a better answer if you describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: "I would like to have a class which, in its constructor, can have knowledge (extract as a string) its instance name." looks clear to me. I can add that I want to use the Matlab variable name as an Identifier for an external database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the variable name that is used to assign the output of a function or class constructor. As you've discovered, the only way to get the object's variable name in the calling workspace is to call another method of the class at which point you can  use `inputname` to query it.

That aside, it's not clear why you need to do this but I'd strongly discourage it. Particularly with `handle` classes, you can have multiple variables point to the *same* object, therefore the object technically has *multiple* names.

Comment: the  `< handle` derivation was there by mistake.